# sublime text 2 find file - search dot separated

Tags: sublimetext2

Using Sublime Text 2, to find a file I control+p and type in the file path and/or file name

If I search for "admin/users" it works fine for the "/"

But...I am working with Laravel, which uses dot separators in many places, for example:

View::make('admin.users.index.blade.php')

which would correspond to:

"admin/users/index.blade.php" file.

How can I customize the Find File to **also** allow typing in "admin.users.index" and not have to remove the dots, as I currently do?

Bonus points: if you know of a plugin that I can simply right-click the name string in the open file, and open that file, I would name my next tomato plant after you.